# Embedding Calabi-Yau manifolds in projective space

Tags: mirror-symmetry, calabi-yau, ample-bundles, projective-varieties

When studying homological mirror symmetry, a lot of work is done not in the setting of complex manifolds, but of smooth (quasi-)projective varieties, see e.g. [a paper from Orlov](http://www.mi-ras.ru/%7Eorlov/papers/trsing.pdf). However, the actual case one wants to consider is usually that of Calabi-Yau-manifolds.

It is usually not explained why the former case includes the latter, although it seems to be used very often that it does. My question is therefore: Can every (possibly non-compact) Calabi-Yau be embedded into projective space, giving a smooth quasiprojective variety (I read that it sometimes can't be included as a projective one)? I assume that to show this one would have to (like for Fano manifolds) construct an ample line bundle over it, as that would already imply the result. If it is possible, how can it be shown, and more importantly if not, why is Orlov's approach even justified?

Maybe a few further remarks: It seems like to embed a complex manifold $X$ into projective space, it must neccessarily be Kähler, as the Kähler structure of $\mathbb{C} P^n$ restricts to one on $X$, but this is obviously fulfilled here. Also, I read the [article on ncatlab about Calabi-Yau-varieties](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Calabi-Yau+variety), and to me it seems like it also supposes that these are equivalent to Calabi-Yau manifolds, although it only describes the analytification direction.

Comment: A quick remark, for the compact case: if your definition of Calabi-Yau manifold is the strongest one, namely holonomy equal to SU(n) or, equivalently, simples connected, trivial canonical bundle and no holomorphic p-forms except for bottom and top degree, then it is automatically projective, by Kodaira's criterion.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems like a very elegant criterion! However I definitely need this result for non-compact Calabi-Yaus, as the LG-models considered by Orlov become a lot more easy to handle in the compact case.

Comment: So, which is your definition of Calabi-Yau? I am curious! P.S. The Kodaira criterion I am speaking about in this situation is "compact Kähler manifold with $H^2(X,\mathcal O_X)=0$ is projective".

Comment: To define superstring theories on it, the manifold $X$ needs to be Kähler, and vanishing of conformal anomalies (or of R-symmetry anomalies, as one wants to perform a topological twist) further constrains the first Chern class to be trivial. That should be everyting (I'm not really an expert so I don't know how this compares to the other definitions, but it seems pretty weak). However, partial or more general results are still very much of interest; but the theory here depends crucially on a holomorphic function $W$ with target $X$, and this function becomes trivial in the compact case.

Comment: Your definition allows every open subset of a Calabi-Yau manifold to be also a Calabi-Yau manifold. For example, the unit ball in complex Euclidean space is a Calabi-Yau manifold in your sense, but not a quasi projective variety, as its closure in projective space is not a projective variety. So you need a better definition, with some sort of completeness or inextensibility, at the least.

Comment: K3 surfaces are not necessarily embeddable in projective space, but they are Calabi Yau in most senses.

Comment: @BenMcKay, indeed, I was tacitly thinking about dimension greater than or equal to three!

Comment: @BenMcKay Thanks! I can't say I completely understand your arguments, but yes, that makes sense. I wonder if it helps to restrict to Calabi-Yau manifolds of dimension 3, as they are the most important cases in HMS, or as diverietti says to the dimension being $\geq 3$.

Comment: @MarkusZetto, you can still take an open ball of dimension three...

Comment: My understanding is that the question is now: is every complete Kaehler manifold with trivial canonical bundle and of complex dimension 3 or more biholomorphic to a quasi projective variety? I don't know the answer.

Comment: @BenMcKay, stated in this form unfortunately the answer is no for trivial reasons: take a non projective complex torus...

Comment: For what it’s worth, these non-compact CYs are generally considered as local models of singularities in compact CYs, which in dimension three are algebraic (see here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30629/are-calabi-yau-manifolds-in-dimension-3-algebraic/30634#30634)  I don’t know if that means that all noncompact CYs arise this way.

Comment: Also, there’s no reason from the physics point of view to restrict to the quasi projective case. To the extent you can make sense of topological string on the manifold, all the mirror symmetry stuff should hold, even if it’s only been proven for algebraic manifolds.